# DataContractSerializer and "URL" xml node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a XML file by using DataContractSerializer which containes node called "URL". Like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<product ID="8717973147527">
<name>Something</name>
<price currency="EUR">9.00</price>
<URL>http://google.com</URL>
<images>
<image>http://google.com</image>
</images>
</product>
</products>
```

After deserialization property mapped to URL stays null. If I rename the xml node to "url" (lower case) or any other word it is working fine. The problem is that I am not able to change the XML, so I must find a way to deserialize it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are a number of places where this could potentially fall down. It would help if you posted the code for your `DataContract` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `XmlAttribute` to set the name as you expect it on the XML file as:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassName
{
    // Here set the Xml Name Attribute
    [XmlAttribute("URL")]
    string Url;  

...
```